# Visually displaying JSON data in a grouped bar chart with d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I need help with visually displaying JSON data using D3.JS. I can get the graphs to show but my problem is that the bars stack up ontop of each other instead of being translated into groups based on the categories they are displaying. Below you can find my code as well as a link to a screengrab of my current output as well as the JSON file im using.

link to screengrab: 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=15x6anl&s=8#.VH3C5HWSw8o

and here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
.rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x0)
.orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); 



 d3.json("ronaldo.json", function(error, data) { 

  console.log(data);

  var playerNames = [] 
  data.forEach(function(d){playerNames.push(d.name)}) 

  var attr = []; 
  data[0]['statistics']['2005'].forEach(function(d){return attr.push(d.attr)}) 
  console.log(attr)

  x0.domain(attr.map(function(d){return d})); 
  //x0.domain(data.map(function(d){return d['statistics']['2005']['attr']})); 
  x1.domain(playerNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(d["statistics"]["2005"], function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Units");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(+d['statistics']['2005']['attr']) + ",0)"; }); 

  state.selectAll("rect") 
        .data(function(d) { return d['statistics']['2005']; })
        .enter().append("rect") 
        .attr("class","bars")
        .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d['attr']); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d['value']); })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.attr);});


  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(playerNames.slice())
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; }); 





}); 

});
```

JSON Data:

```
[
      {
     "name": "Cristiano Ronaldo",
     "age" : 28,
     "team": "Real Madrid",
      "statistics" : {
         "2005" : [
            {"attr" :"Appearances", 
         "value": 100},
            {"attr" :"Goals", 
         "value": 92},
            {"attr" :"Yellow Cards", 
         "value": 10}, 
        {"attr" :"Red Cards", 
         "value": 1}    
         ] 
      }
      },
     {
     "name": "Lionel Messi",
     "age" : 29,
     "team": "Barcelona",
      "statistics" : {
         "2005" : [
            {"attr" :"Appearances", 
         "value": 90},
            {"attr" :"Goals", 
         "value": 87},
            {"attr" :"Yellow Cards", 
         "value": 13}, 
        {"attr" :"Red Cards", 
         "value": 43}   
         ] 
      }
      }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you have a `x0` and a `x1` scales but your issue is here.

You should have only one scale that you use in:

- xAxis (be careful to override the scale of xAxis after you defined `x1`)
- `.attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d['attr']); })`

I have made a small jsFiddle with the solution I suggested but since I don't know what you wanted to see exactly, I'm not sure it's perfect: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/uzmur5kb/

All I did was: change the `.attr("x", ...)` line to:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return x0(d['attr']); })
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The reason why I have a x0 and and x1 scale is because the x0 scale handles the spacing of each of the groupings on the x-axis (hence, when multiple players are compared, their respective graphs are split up based on "appearances", "goals" etc). The x1 scale handles the spacings of the bars within their respective groupings. Hence the final display should display multiple bars (in this instance two) per catagory on the x-axis. So the only thing missing now are the bars for the other player (Messi)

Comment: That's a completely different task but I hope that my answer pointed you to the right direction :) 
You now have to make room for 2 bars per existing bar instead of 1 right now. Playing with the x attribute and the width should do the trick if I understood correctly your explanation.